# Can you gunzip the contents of a get request in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gzip

I'm fetching some JSON with angular as:

```
$http({
    url: 'https://www.somemachine.com/getdata', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

The data it's receiving is quite large, and I'm happy to gzip the source but is there a way to gunzip it when my `$http` method fetches it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the source is already zipped, just ensure the Accept-Encoding header is set to gzip on the request:

```
$http.get('https://www.somemachine.com/getdata', { headers: { 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip' } }
).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The browser will automatically unzip it when it sees the Content-Encoding=gzip header on the response.

Comment: You first sentence doesn't make sense. Why would the client say "I want it zipped" when the server zips it anyway?

Comment: @zeroflagL The server should only zip it if the client says "I can accept gzipped data"

Comment: Most browsers forbid changing the Accept-Encoding header nowadays.